# Python return list out of list of lists when variable in list is found

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm a Python beginner. I'm trying to return a list from a list of lists into a new list of lists. I've looked extensively at similar questions, but cannot find the answer.

```
l1 = [['a','b','c','d'],['b','c','d','f'],['b','c','a','f']]
```

I would like to loop over l1 to check if 'a' is in a list, and when true then add that list to a new list of lists l2. I got this far (not very far):

```
l2 = []
for selector in l1:
    if 'a' in selector:
        l2.append(*#I don't know this part*)
```

What i would like is this result:

```
l2 = [['a','b','c','d'],['b','c','a','f']]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `result.append(selector)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over the inner lists

```
>>> [sub for sub in l1 if 'a' in sub]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'a', 'f']]
```

To complete the snippet of code you showed above, the way you'd use a `for` loop is

```
l2 = []
for selector in l1:
    if 'a' in selector:
        l2.append(selector)

>>> l2
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'a', 'f']]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that solves it! Just one word from getting there myself I see. Slightly embarrassed